How to determine number of rows in a dataset in the do loop
I have below SAS code
data original_data;
    input var1 $ var2;
    datalines;
A 12
B 19
C 23
D 40
;
run;
data original_data1;
    set original_data;
    do i = 1 to 4;
       new_val = var2 + 44;
    end;
run;

In the line do i = 1 to 4 I put 4 manually as the number of rows of original_data, however I wonder how can I put that information dynamically based on the number of rows in given dataset (e.g. nrow() function in R)

Why do you want to know the  number of rows?  Your example code doesn't really illustrate the need.  I think you might be misunderstanding how the DATA step works.

I inserted [-8.53881563e+07, -3.81637485e+08, -3.81637485e+08] in your FN function. Then I inserted [-8.53881563e+07, -3.81637485e+09, -3.81637485e+09] and got a value 3 orders of magnitude lower. And you can continue that trend. I very much doubt that there is a minimum to your function (calculating the first and second derivative would probably easily show this to be a fact).

The example on pythonguides.com is incorrect; that function also doesn't have a minimum. The fact that it shows some (very large, negative) values is likely only because the number of iterations is exceeded or something similar. But that example is really bad, as it also doesn't check the various result values & messages that minimize returns.

The SAS DATA step is an implicit loop.  In the simple use case of a step with a single SET statement that reads one input dataset, the DATA step will automatically iterate through every row of the dataset.  On each iteration, the SET statement executes and reads one row of data.  On the final iteration, the SET statement will execute and attempt to read data but it will hit a (logical) end of file mark, and the step will complete.
So this code:
data original_data1;
    set original_data;
    do i = 1 to 4;
       new_val = var2 + 44;
    end;
run;

Does not make sense.  For row #1 of the input dataset, it will execute the assignment statement four times.  Then for row #2 of the dataset, it will execute the assignment statement four times, etc.
To create a new variable, you only need to execute the assignment statement once (for each row).  You can do that like:
data want ;
  set original_data ;
  new_val = var2 + 44;
run ;

You don't need to tell SAS how many rows are in original_data. SAS just processes the data that is there, one row at a time, until there is no more data to process.
The output datasets work.original_data1 and work.want will have the same data, other than the fact that work.orignal_datat1 will have an extra variable, i.

Thanks for this elaborate explanation. I am coming from Python background so somewhat confused about SAS way of working

Have you looked over this https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000173782.htm?
You can use set nobs.
set original_data nobs=num_rows;

